# Radius of convergence of $\frac{x}{sinh(x)}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

The power series representation of real hyperbolic sine function, as  $sinh(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$. And its radius of convergence is, of course, $\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(2n+2)!}} = \infty$. My question is the radius of convergence of $\frac{x}{sinh(x)}$
By calculation, I can get

> $\frac{x}{sinh(x)} = \frac{1}{1+x^2(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{x^2}{120}+ \cdots)} = 1 - x^2(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{x^2}{120}+ \cdots) + x^4(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{x^2}{120}+ \cdots)^2 - x^6(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{x^2}{120}+ \cdots)^3 + \cdots$

But, can I justify the second equality for $|x|>1$? Actually it use geometry series, so I think it is justified when $|x|<1$. However, I know this equation works for $|x|>1$, so I want to prove that radius of convergence of $\frac{x}{sinh(x)}$ is $\infty$. Can you give some hint?

Comment: $\sinh(i\pi)=i\sin\pi=0$, so I expect its radius is $\pi$.

Comment: @Michael Oh, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(z) = \frac{z}{\sinh z} \equiv \frac{iz}{\sin iz}$ has a removable singularity at $x=0$, so you can define $f(0)=1$. The radius of convergence for the Taylor series for this function centered at $z=0$ is the distance from $0$ to the nearest true singularity, which is at $\pm i\pi$. So I would say the series converges for $|z|<\pi$.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think expand this problem on the complex plane.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because it isn't $\infty$: $z^{-1}\sinh{z}$ has zeros at $z=\pm i\pi$, so $z/\sinh{z}$ has poles at these points, and hence is not analytic there. Therefore the power series representation, which is an analytic function when it converges, cannot converge to the function outside the open disk of radius $\pi$. On the other hand, $z/\sinh{z}$ is analytic inside this disk, so the power series does converge inside. Hence the radius of convergence must be $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer. :)